# Is it common to call some kind of figures "visual"?

Tags: meaning

This [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-perform-exploratory-data-analysis-with-seaborn-97e3413e841d) call this figure

[image]

"LotArea visual".

Usually, I see people call this a figure or a plot. "Figure" is perfectly acceptable, since almost all of textbooks call it "Figure".

The question is: is it common to call this kind of figures "visual"?

Comment: The term "visual" is (or at least was) sometimes used in oral presentations to refer to graphics that were presented to the audience during the speech.  I'm guessing the term is falling out of use, though, as video displays during speeches are becoming hum-drum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overreading the source here.

The article is about using visual interpretations of data.

The graph shown would be referred to as a figure. They may have titled the graphic with the word visual as a reference to the subject.

Yes, you could call a figure in a text a visual, no one could call that incorrect. But, figure is the more common term.